# Python Regex to find stock tickers (stock symbols)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regex that finds ticker symbols in bodies of text. However it is a bit of a struggle to get one to do everything I need.

Example:

> This is a $test to show what I would LIKE to match. If $YOU look below you will FIND the list of simulated tickers ($STOck symbols) I would like to match.

So in this case I would like to match the following from the above:

- test
- LIKE
- YOU
- FIND
- STOck

I am trying to get:

- any word after a "$" sign (not including the $), case insensitive
- any word that is ALL CAPS and between 3-6 characters long

I've tried:

- `\b[A-Z]{3,6}\b` but that matches pretty much every word
- `\$[^3-6\s]\S*` but that includes the $ and also ignores any ALL CAPS without a dollar sign

Comment: Something like this? (\$(\w+)|([A-Z]{3,6}))

Comment: Something like that yes, but that still takes in the $ and also matches all lowercase words between 3-6 characters. It is similar to what I already have, however I am after something that only matches 3-6 characters of words that are ALL CAPS and matches everything AFTER a $ and before the space. So in the sentence: THIS is a test to $see the $MATCHES. Would match THIS, see and MATCHES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
import re

s = 'This is a $test to show what I would LIKE to match. If $YOU look below you will FIND the list of simulated tickers ($STOck symbols) I would like to match.'

print(re.findall(r'(?<=\$)\w+|[A-Z]{3,6}', s))
```

Output:

```
['test', 'LIKE', 'YOU', 'FIND', 'STOck']
```

`(?<=\$)` is a lookbehind assertion which matches a leading dollar sign without including the match in the result.
(Precisely speaking, it matches the *boundary* just after the dollar sign rather than the character itself.)